# Storing ArrayList in Excel using Apache POI HSSF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a data list:

```
List data1 = (List) session.getAttribute("data");
```

Now, I want this data to be stored in an Excel file:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet");

HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("lOGINID");
rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("CUSTOMERID");
rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("updatetime");

int index = 1;
for (itr = data1.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    // what to write here?
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of `data1`?

Comment: you have found all the needed methods: call within the for loop: `HSSFRow row=sheet.createRow(i++) and create 3 cells with the data from the current iterator element.

Comment: Can you please write in form of code

Comment: {Loginid, customerid, updatetime}

Answer (score 1):

You haven't clearly stated what your List holds. `List data1 = (List) session.getAttribute("data");`  It must be `List<SomeClass>`.

You can simply iterate over the list, pull the object on current index, create new row and fill the values in cells

```
for (int i = 0; i < data1.size(); i++) { //iterate over the list

   SomeClass data = data1.get(i);//pull the object on current index i

   HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i + 1); //create new row

   //fill the values
   row.createCell(0).setCellValue(data.field1);
   row.createCell(1).setCellValue(data.field2);
   row.createCell(2).setCellValue(data.field3);
```

A complete example assuming the list contains `RowData`,:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
 

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

    void writeList() throws IOException {
        //read data , RowData can be different in your case
        List<RowData> data1 = (List<RowData>) session.getAttribute("data"); 

        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet");

        HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow(0); //header

        rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("lOGINID");
        rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("CUSTOMERID");
        rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("updatetime");

        for (int i = 0; i < data1.size(); i++) {

            RowData data = data1.get(i);//rows

            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);

            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(data.loginId);
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(data.customerId);
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(data.time);
        }

        //write to file
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.xlsx")) {
            wb.write(out);
        }
    }


    @AllArgsConstructor
    class RowData {
        String loginId;
        String customerId;
        String time;
    }
```